# Computing expected value of the error in log-linear model

Tags: statistics, expected-value

Let $u \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$. Then, I want to compute the expectation of $e^u$. Basically $u$ is the disturbance term of log-linear regression model, when I exponentiate the regression equation.

I proceed as follows:
\begin{equation}
E(e^u) = \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} u (2 \pi)^{- 1/2} \sigma^{-1/2} e^{- \frac{u^2}{2 \sigma^2}} du
\end{equation}

How should I proceed next?

The textbook says that the expected value is $e^{\sigma^2 /2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to compute
$$\int_{u=-\infty}^{\infty} e^u\  \frac{\exp({-u^2/2\sigma^2)}}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi }}\, du.$$

Notice that $$
\begin{aligned} \frac{\sigma^2}2 - \frac{ (u - \sigma^2)^2}{2 \sigma^2} =&\ \frac{\sigma^2}2  - \frac{u^2 - 2 u \sigma^2 + \sigma^4}{2 \sigma^2}   \\
=&\ \frac{\sigma^2}2  -  \frac{u^2}{2\sigma^2}  +  u  - \frac{\sigma^2}2   \\
=&\  u -u^2/2\sigma^2.   
\end{aligned}$$

So,
$$\begin{aligned} 
\int_{u=-\infty}^{\infty} e^u \ \frac{\exp({-u^2/2\sigma^2)}}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi }}\, du &= \int_{u=-\infty}^{\infty}  \frac{\exp({u-u^2/2\sigma^2)}}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi }}\, du \\
&= \int_{u=-\infty}^{\infty}  \frac{\exp\left( \frac{\sigma^2}2 - \frac{ (u - \sigma^2)^2}{2 \sigma^2}\right)  }{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi }}\, du \\
&= \exp(\sigma^2/2)  \int_{u=-\infty}^{\infty}  \frac{\exp\left(  - \frac{ (u - \sigma^2)^2}{2 \sigma^2}\right)  }{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi }}\, du \\
&=  \exp(\sigma^2/2)
\end{aligned}$$
where the last equality holds because the integral of the pdf of a Gaussian random varible is 1.